# Tooltips, CSS only, Show text tooltip on mouseover using a class to define the text

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to CSS, but have what seems to be an unique question.
I have a TL;DR if you want to skip to it.

I've seen MANY tutorials on how to display tooltips, but none answer this exact scenario, so it may not be possible.

Backstory:
I've been playing around with tables to show a calendar and have made it so I can simply change the class of a td cell to change the background colour.

This allows me to very easily edit my HTML, changing a single class on each line to change a date from available to booked. For instance:

```
HTML: <td class="b">1</td>
CSS: .b {  color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #CC0033; font-size: 12px; text-align: center}
```

in my CSS, I have the "b" set to turn the background red, indicating this date is no longer available.

```
HTML: <td class="a">1</td>
CSS: .a { font-size: 12px; text-align: center}
```

The above would have no background colour and would indicate the date is available.

Now, I have been able to get a tooltip to show based on what class the cell is set to, but it seems I have to set every cell with the text, like this:

```
<td class="a">1<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text here</span></td>
```

which I guess is a way to do it, but it takes more time to edit, and I want it so I can display 2-3 different messages depending on which class I select in the td class.

So the question:
Is there a way I can set it up so,

If the td class = "a", a tooltip will show up saying "Available"

OR If the td class = "b", a tooltip will show up saying "Booked"

OR If the td class = "r", a tooltip will show up saying "Reserved"

when I mouseover the cell, without having to set those responses over and over again in every td cell.
IE: Without doing something like this:

```
<td class="a">1<span class="tooltiptext">Available</span></td>
<td class="b">2<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
<td class="r">3<span class="tooltiptext">Reserved</span></td>
<td class="b">4<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
<td class="b">5<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
<td class="b">6<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
<td class="a">7<span class="tooltiptext">Available</span></td>
<td class="b">8<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
<td class="b">9<span class="tooltiptext">Booked</span></td>
```

I'd rather it was simply like this:

```
<td class="a">1</td>
<td class="b">2</td>
<td class="r">3</td>
<td class="b">4</td>
<td class="b">5</td>
<td class="b">6</td>
<td class="a">7</td>
<td class="b">8</td>
<td class="b">9</td>
```

and the tooltip text set elsewhere, but displayed on mouseover depending on which td class was set.

I feel I'm explaining this really badly.

---

Here is a snippet of my CSS using "t" as a test class, just in case you need it. Please don't worry about the formatting or positioning of the tooltip yet, I can fix that easily enough if I can get it working how I want:

```
.t {  color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #FFA500; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; title:"Example";}
.t:hover .tooltiptext{ visibility: visible; }
.t .tooltiptext {visibility: hidden; width: 120px; background-color: black; color: #fff; text-align: center; border-radius: 6px; padding: 5px 0; position: absolute; z-index: 1; }
```

and the relevant piece of HTML:

```
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="t">1<span class="tooltiptext">Test Message</span></td>
                                    <td class="b">2</td>
                                    <td class="b">3</td>
                                    <td class="b">4</td>
                                    <td class="b">5</td>
                                    <td class="b">6</td>
                                    <td class="a">7</td>
                                </tr>
```

So, in the above, can I relocate the span somewhere else so it only appears once, and is referenced depending on which td class is defined, and have 2 other spans with different messages, which are defined by the td class "a" and "b"?

An ideal solution to this would be something I can do in the CSS like this:

```
.t .tooltiptext {custom-text: "This text will display on hover"; 
visibility: hidden; 
width: 120px; 
Etc...
}
```

---

TL;DR Is there a 'CSS only' way of making the tooltip text display different text by only changing the td class?

Comment: Can you not just assign your element to multiple classes(`class="booked available reserved"`) and then just style the each class for each state (booked, available, reserved) the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in pure CSS you can't

- relocate the `span` somewhere else (only in Javascript, Jquery, etc etc)

But if each `td` with a specific class has a `span` element you can display different text in this way:

```css
span {
  display:none;
  /*Etc etc*/
}
td:hover span {
  display:inherit;
}
.a span:after {
  content: 'something about class A';
}
.b span:after {
  content: 'something about class B';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">1<span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="b">2<span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">3<span></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks like the path I need to follow, however I cannot seem to integrate it into my current page.

If I take a single part of the table and insert it, (IE a selection from the table of the first 3 months) it works as intended, however in the nested setting of the rest of the tables in the current page, showing the full year and some text above the calendar, hovering over any 'tr' element makes _all_ of the spans show their content!

I shall have to do some debugging to find out why this is happening tomorrow. (If you know of a reason why this would be happening, Please do reply!)

Comment: Oh, you probably didn't close each element ('td' or 'tr')